# How to create a timers relay in python

Tags: python, timer

What I mean how we can create different timers in python related to each other, consider it 6 timers A, B, C, D, E and F, timer a start from 0 them when timer A equal 1 second timer B start and when timer B equal 1 second then timer C start and so on.

Comment: What aspects of this do you need help with, and which have you already implemented?

Comment: looks like cron job

Answer (score 0):

you can do it very simply with

```
import time 
time.sleep(number)
```

but you have to understand that sleep, pauses the script and prevented execution until the timer is finished

here is the doc, look at it to do more sophisticated things without pausing the program

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
This function take a numbers of rele and do an ***infinite loop.***
Ex:

- if n = 3

- the cycle was 1-2-3-1-2-3-(...)

```
import time
def startRele(rele):
    for r in range(rele):
        print("--- wait 1 sec ---")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"start relé", r+1)
        if r == rele-1:
            startRele(rele)
            
numRele = 5 
startRele(numRele);
```

**Solution 2**

same as one but the cycle terminate after finish the num of relé.
Ex:

- n=31

- 1-2-3 (end)

```
import time

def startRele(rele):
    for r in range(rele):
        print("--- wait 1 sec ---")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"start relé", r+1)
        
numRele = 5 
startRele(numRele);
```